# React: findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition

Tags: reactjs

I very new to React, and have run into an issue, which I really cant seem to find any solution on...

Basically, I have a button which triggers a state to open/hide a modal component... When clicking the button, im getting the error:

index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here:

So I tried adding a ref to my Modal component, didnt work, also tried creating a wrapper around the Modal component with a ref, didn't help either?

I got the error after adding the connect() from redux - Before adding the connect() method to the component, I didn't get an error?

The code is VERY simple:

```
<div>
            <button onClick={toggleTrueFalse}>Click here to open a modal</button>
            <CSSTransition
                in={showModal}
                timeout={300}
                classNames="dialog"
                unmountOnExit
            >
                <Modal modalHeaderContent={modalHeaderContent} modalContent={modalContent}/>
            </CSSTransition>
        </div>
```

the method to change the state of the modal is:

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
const toggleTrueFalse = () => setShowModal(!showModal);
```

Im guessing the solution would be rather simple, but just cant seem to find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found a working solution as the GIThub page of react-transition-group:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/668